# How do I set up Yahoo! Mail or Gmail as the default email (mailto:) handler of Opera?

Tags: email, gmail, opera, yahoo-mail

How do I setup Yahoo! Mail or Gmail as the default email (`mailto:`) handler of Opera?

Right now, I can only choose between Yandex, Fastmail and Mail.ru:
[image: I can only access Yandex, Fastmail and Mail.ru by default]

How do I set this, in such a way that Yahoo! Mail or Gmail's interface will open if I click on a mailto: link, and preferably with the subject line set by the `mailto:` link already set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add and set Yahoo! Mail as the default Opera `mailto:` handler, the file, *webmailproviders.ini* must be edited (in 64-bit Windows, this is at `C:\Program Files\Opera\defaults`). Make a backup of it first, for safety, and then edit it to also include:

> [Yahoo! Mail]
>   ID=3
>   URL=http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=%t&Subject=%j
>   ICON=http://mail.yahoo.com/favicon.ico

Depending on the entries already existing, change the `'3'` in the `ID=3` line to another number, to avoid it having a duplicate ID. (In my case, `ID=3` does not have a duplicate id.)

Then go to Preferences > Advanced > Programs and edit `mailto:` in Opera for the action to use a web mail service rather than Open with another application, selecting Yahoo! Mail which should now be in the drop-down list.

[Source](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/findpost.pl?id=13407572)

Comment: Just want to add: That can be done also for [Gmail](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/4674/opera-10-set-gmail-as-the-default-email-client/)

Comment: @nixda That's true. However, I have no experience implementing it in Opera, so I didn't put it as part of my answer (and question). If you have experience implementing it in Opera, feel free to make an answer here (you could suggest an edit to, or I could edit my question to further generalize it to include Gmail).

Answer (score 1):

There might be some interest to the following, since Gmail is also a popular email provider

**Set up Gmail as email handler for opera**

- Make all the steps galacticninja has stated in his answer
- except the editing part of the `webmailproviders.ini.`
  Instead use the code below

```
[Gmail] 
ID=3
URL=https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s
ICON=https://mail.google.com/favicon.ico
```

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/4674/opera-10-set-gmail-as-the-default-email-client/)

Comment: Will this automatically set up the Subject line? (Like in Yahoo! Mail's in [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/507198/10259)?)

Comment: I just clicked on a mailto:link within a website. It automatically inserts the webpage title as subject.

Comment: I was asking, because in my answer about Yahoo! Mail, the Subject line's variable is `%j` and the email's variable is `%t`. This is different from the variable used here, which is `%s` (whole `mailto:` URI). Since I don't use Gmail as an email handler in Opera, I can't test this and am wondering if that solution will also include the Subject (not necessarily the webpage title) if it is included in the `mailto:` URI.

Comment: I did some research with no luck. `&url` splits up into `&to` and `&su`. Gmail did use `&su` instead of the normal `&subject` in earlier versions. I tried it with every combination I could imagine., but without any luck. Nearly 1h of googling without finding any reference for gmail parameters. :(

Comment: Maybe I found something. I compared the raw html code of the working and not working example from above. It seems all sites with this meta tag [`meta property="og:title"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535405/what-is-the-attribute-property-ogtitle-inside-meta-tag) can submit a subject to gmail